# Two questions about MergEXT's mergSocial

Tags: livecode

1. It does not seem to support posting unicode text (e.g., Chinese) in the message. Hope an updated version will fix this.
2. Is there an Android version? If no, what is the best alternative?

Answer (score 0):

RE #1: With the unicode support coming in LiveCode 7 it's highly likely the externals interface will get an upgrade so users won't need to specify the encoding of strings in the external call. So at this stage I'm waiting to see what we get there.

RE #2: There's no Android version of mergSocial as there's no equivalent to the Social framework on Android. The closest thing might be a sharing Intent however that's much closer to the mergPopActivity command which I have implemented in mergAndroid. It's probable something could be implemented using Facebook and Twitter SDKs for Android.